# alibaba easyexcel jar inside imported a poi jar class ,but outer have one poi jar which may conflict with easyexcel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

First here is the exception code

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at com.alibaba.excel.context.GenerateContextImpl.<init>(GenerateContextImpl.java:64)
    at com.alibaba.excel.write.ExcelBuilderImpl.init(ExcelBuilderImpl.java:35)
    at com.alibaba.excel.ExcelWriter.<init>(ExcelWriter.java:50)
    at com.landray.kmss.km.archive.excel.DownloadServlet.doGet(DownloadServlet.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:292)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:303)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:143)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:303)
    at com.landray.kmss.sys.authentication.integration.KmssProcessingFilterProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(KmssProcessingFilterProxy.java:177)
    at com.landray.kmss.third.pda.interfaces.ThirdPdaRedirectFilter.doFilter(ThirdPdaRedirectFilter.java:103)
    at com.landray.kmss.sys.authentication.integration.KmssProcessingFilterProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(KmssProcessingFilterProxy.java:183)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:246)
    at com.landray.kmss.sys.authentication.integration.KmssProcessingFilterProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(KmssProcessingFilterProxy.java:183)
    at com.landray.kmss.sys.admin.threadmonitor.service.spring.SysAdminThreadMonitorFilter.doFilter(SysAdminThreadMonitorFilter.java:54)
    at com.landray.kmss.sys.authentication.integration.KmssProcessingFilterProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(KmssProcessingFilterProxy.java:183)
    at com.landray.kmss.sys.authentication.integration.KmssProcessingFilterProxy.doFilter(KmssProcessingFilterProxy.java:55)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:303)
    at com.landray.kmss.sys.authentication.integration.CheckVerificationCodeFilter.doFilter(CheckVerificationCodeFilter.java:115)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:303)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:220)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:303)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:120)
    at com.landray.kmss.web.filter.AcegiFilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(AcegiFilterToBeanProxy.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.landray.kmss.web.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
2019-03-15 10:17:25,643 [ERROR] ==== http-8080-4: com.landray.kmss.util.KmssMessageWriter.logError(208)
    很抱歉，操作失败！，URL=http://localhost:8080/ekp/resource/jsp/jsperror.jsp?type=500

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook
    at com.alibaba.excel.context.GenerateContextImpl.<init>(GenerateContextImpl.java:64)
    at com.alibaba.excel.write.ExcelBuilderImpl.init(ExcelBuilderImpl.java:35)
    at com.alibaba.excel.ExcelWriter.<init>(ExcelWriter.java:50)
    at com.landray.kmss.km.archive.excel.DownloadServlet.doGet(DownloadServlet.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:292)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:303)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:143)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:303)
    at com.landray.kmss.sys.authentication.integration.KmssProcessingFilterProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(KmssProcessingFilterProxy.java:177)
    at com.landray.kmss.third.pda.interfaces.ThirdPdaRedirectFilter.doFilter(ThirdPdaRedirectFilter.java:103)
    at com.landray.kmss.sys.authentication.integration.KmssProcessingFilterProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(KmssProcessingFilterProxy.java:183)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:246)
    at com.landray.kmss.sys.authentication.integration.KmssProcessingFilterProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(KmssProcessingFilterProxy.java:183)
    at com.landray.kmss.sys.admin.threadmonitor.service.spring.SysAdminThreadMonitorFilter.doFilter(SysAdminThreadMonitorFilter.java:54)
    at com.landray.kmss.sys.authentication.integration.KmssProcessingFilterProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(KmssProcessingFilterProxy.java:183)
    at com.landray.kmss.sys.authentication.integration.KmssProcessingFilterProxy.doFilter(KmssProcessingFilterProxy.java:55)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:303)
    at com.landray.kmss.sys.authentication.integration.CheckVerificationCodeFilter.doFilter(CheckVerificationCodeFilter.java:115)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:303)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:220)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:303)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:120)
    at com.landray.kmss.web.filter.AcegiFilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(AcegiFilterToBeanProxy.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.landray.kmss.web.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 50 more
```

I can search org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook class in the project using `Ctrl + Shift + T` ,but only one class I can see.I hava tried it with `IntelliJ IDEA` purely,and I can get the right thing as I expected.But when I make the code and jar into my official workspace which have so many other jars ,I think may be two jar are conflicting with each other.
Here is my imgs.

https://img.shownmmp.top/easyexcel.png
https://img.shownmmp.top/poi.png

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have `apache poi 3.7` in class path. But this version does not provide `SXSSF`. This was introduced in version `3.8`. Having multiple different versions pf `apache poi` in class path is not supported.

Comment: Then what should I do now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Maven or any other build tool in which you can easily control which dependencies are being used and added into resulting artifact. Also with Maven you can explicitly exclude conflicting transitive dependencies.

Comment: I extractly understand your word ，but I can not do that because this is  an old project which include some company's jars  and it did not publish.

Comment: Either use Intellij or cleanup your official workspace in eclipse to use only one compatible version of `poi`. BTW with Maven you can setup local repo on your machine upload your company's jars there manually